# what is the return value of Delete Method?

Tags: return-value, sql-delete, petapoco

In PetaPOCO ( http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco ) Delete method returns an integer value.

What I want to know is, what is the return value of Delete Method? Is it "Number of Records" affected? or is it some "error-code"?

I basically want to confirm that the DELETE operation was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's the Number of Records affected. If there's an error it will throw an exception